# Cygwin terminal / shell session in mobaxterm

Tags: windows, cygwin, mobaxterm

I have (64-bit) Cygwin install on my Windows machine; and I'm also using mobaxterm 12.4.

How do I get my mobaxterm to...

- Start a Cygwin shell session? Or better yet
- Use Cygwin as the default when launching a "Local Terminal"?

Comment: Have you tried the mobaxterm cygwin plugin? [MobaXterm Xserver with SSH, telnet, RDP, VNC and X11 - Plugins](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/plugins.html)

Comment: the internal mobxaterm terminal is a cygwin, in configuratio->terminal->local shell you have different options (cmd, powershell, zsh,...) but no options to add an external one.

Comment: @DavidPostill: What plugin exactly? There isn't a plugin named "cygwin".

Comment: @Zina: That's... annoying :-( I want it to use _my_ full-fledged cygwin, with the Cygwin home directory for my user and everything.

Comment: well, maybe running cygwin from within the mobaxterm local terminal might work, look into the execute command on start option...maybe you will be able to work around it with it

Answer (score 2):

it's also possible to create a shell session with the 'Bash (external)' option

Menu Sessions -> New Session -> Shell -> Bash (external) -> Advanced Shell Settings -> Distribution Directory -> C:\path\to\cygwin64

tested with version 22.3

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use a CMD terminal that starts a cygwin BASH session upon startup, as follows (adapt the cygwin location and the user to your situation):

```
MobaXterm | Session | Shell | Terminal Shell: Cmd | Advanced Shell Settings | Execute:
set HOME=/home/<user>;
C:\\Localdata\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash --login
```